# Не работает template_name в django 1.11

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь настроить сброс пароля на сайте, через отправку письма на почту. Работает, но не подключаются шаблоны в приложении авторизации, то есть после оправки письма заходит в Администрирование Django, а после перехода по ссылки из письма заходить в Администрирование Django, хотя должны работать мои шаблоны.

```
 url(r'^password-reset/done/$', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
    template_name='account/registration/password_reset_done.html'),
    name='password_reset_done'),
```

Менял последовательность подключения приложения в settings, так же в главном приложении менял последовательность у -

```
url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Переименовывал шаблоны, не помогло. 
Прошу помощи или подсказки.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен, всем спасибо за участие. Если вдруг такая же проблема, то добавьте в PasswordResetView:

```
    email_template_name='account/registr/password_reset_email.html',
    success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_reset_done'),
```

в PasswordResetConfirmView:

```
    success_url=reverse_lazy('account:password_reset_complete'),
```

и будет вам счастье! :)